# clearInterval / setInterval

Tags: javascript, clearinterval

I am using the following script to display jpg images as an animation:

```
var interval;

function Play() {
  setInterval(Playimages, 100);
}

function Stop() {
  alert("stop");

  clearInterval(interval);
}

function Playimages() {
  i = (i < sl - 1) ? (i + 1) : 0;

  $('#Image1').attr('src', images[i].src);
}
```

Play works well, however I can not stop or pause; there is a mistake in my clearInterval.  Would appreciate your suggestions. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You never assign the *interval id* to `interval`. Should be

```
interval = setInterval(Playimages, 100);
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to change

```
 setInterval(Playimages, 100);
```

to

```
interval = setInterval(Playimages, 100);
```

`setInterval` returns an id which can be used with `clearInterval`. In your code `interval` is probably undefined, so `clearInterval` does nothing because it has no reference.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the interval id to `interval`.

```
var interval;

function Play() {
  interval = setInterval(Playimages, 100);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign the interval variable in setInterval

```
interval = setInterval(Playimages, 100);
clearInterval(interval);
```